# Unexpected Error in Play Store Developer Console

Tags: google-chrome, google-play

I didn't have this problem before but for the last 2 days, I can't seem to open any of my apps in Developer Console. I log in to the Console without any problem and click&go to anything except my apps without any problem. However once I click on my apps it just brings out the error: "Unexpected Error, please try again."

The thing is... It only happens in Chrome. I tried with Edge and it works perfectly. I deleted cache and cookies in the Chrome but still no solution.

Comment: i have the same problem with my panel. did you find any solution?
Galiba Türk'sün kardeş, benim panelde aynı. Sanırım TR'ye özel bi problem. Başka browserlarda denedin mi?
Edit: dikkatimi çekti de, sanırım son chrome güncellemesinden sonra oldu bu durum, en son güncellemeyi yapmadan önce sorun yoktu.

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with chrome worldwide. I have seen other problems like this. My developer console is opening in microsoft edge but not in chrome. Dediğiniz gibi chrome da bir sorun var muhtemelen edge de açılıyor.

Comment: I tried in Edge and Firefox. Both of them works without any problems. However Chrome still brings up the error. Not sure if it's worldwide. If it were, they would have solved it already.